# How can you change only one class of multiple buttons rendered with map

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render multiple items with different names, but I want to change the class of those items one by one instead of changing them all at once by applying the className to the button.

The line that I'm trying to change is this one:

```
  {items.map(item => (
          <button className="cards__button" onClick={pushPokemon}>{item.name}</button>
        ))}
```

So I want to change the button for each name that is rendered but apply a different class to each of them. Is there any way that can be achieved?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import '../style/style.css'

function Cards() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState([])
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [highScore, setHighScore] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=12")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(({ results }) => {
      setItems(results);
    });
}, []);

useEffect(() => console.log(clicked), [clicked]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(count > highScore) {
    setHighScore(count)
  }
}, [clicked])
console.log(count)

const pushPokemon = (e) => {
  var pokemon = e.target.innerHTML;

   items.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());


  if(!clicked.includes(pokemon)) {
      setClicked([...clicked, pokemon]);
      setCount(count + 1)
  } else {
      setCount(0)
      setClicked([])
  }
};
    return (
        <div>
        <div>
        Score: {count}
        </div>
        <div>
        High Score: {highScore}
        </div>
        {items.map(item => (
          <button className="cards__button" onClick={pushPokemon}>{item.name}</button>
        ))}

        </div>
    )
}

export default Cards
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define class dictionary and use it like this.

```
...
classDict = {
    "first_id" : "cards_button",
    "second_id": "else"
}
...
{items.map(item => (
    <button className={classDict[item.id]} onClick={pushPokemon}>{item.name}</button>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be help full to you. Now you are adding class names dynamically.

Like:

cards__button__0

cards__button__1

.
.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import '../style/style.css'

function Cards() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState([])
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [highScore, setHighScore] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=12")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(({ results }) => {
      setItems(results);
    });
}, []);

useEffect(() => console.log(clicked), [clicked]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(count > highScore) {
    setHighScore(count)
  }
}, [clicked])
console.log(count)

const pushPokemon = (e) => {
  var pokemon = e.target.innerHTML;

   items.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());


  if(!clicked.includes(pokemon)) {
      setClicked([...clicked, pokemon]);
      setCount(count + 1)
  } else {
      setCount(0)
      setClicked([])
  }
};
    return (
        <div>
        <div>
        Score: {count}
        </div>
        <div>
        High Score: {highScore}
        </div>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <button className={`cards__button__${index}`} onClick={pushPokemon}>{item.name}</button>
        ))}

        </div>
    )
}

export default Cards
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```